# Extract MSI file from Flash Player 13 instalation exe file

Tags: windows-installer, adobe, powershell-2.0, flash, silent-installer

I recently extracted an Acrobat Reader install exe file by starting the exe file and before hitting continue I went to Start and run and typeed '%ProgramData%\Adobe\Setup' and hit OK.
From there I was able to edit the MSI file in Adobe Customization wizard.  I did this so i could silently install, stop auto-updates, and stop reboot prompt upon installation in a powershell 2.0 script.
How do i do this same MSI extraction process for Flash Player 13?

Below is the link to how to extract the Adobe Reader MSI file:
https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1132310

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the MSI is available for download from Adobe, and is probably a better solution.

http://www.adobe.com/uk/products/flashplayer/distribution3.html